# Displaying a checklist before commit/comments in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

Currently we use TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN as our source control. I have altered the pre-commit hook successfully to block unwanted files etc being committed to the repository. But what I want to achieve now is a check-list that will act as aide memoir before committing.

Is this possible? If so what is required to be done I can't see how it will work with the pre-commit hook as I would want the check-list displayed when they hit commit on the context menu to bring up all the changed files and the log message?

Comment: I think TortoiseSVN Hook Scripts are the way to go here but has anyone any guidance in how best to achieve this as it means everyone updating their own client machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yip TortoiseSVN Client hooks were the way to go

I grabbed the StartCommit.js file from the SVN repository and then tailored it to output what I wanted.

Then I simply created a hook calling WScript \StartCommit.js

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [this pre-commit hook example](http://subversion.tigris.org/tools_contrib.html#pre_commit_check_py)? Some variant of it was used in a shop I used to work at and prevented a lot of common mistakes.